# ASP.NET MVC 4 Forcing Html.ActionLink to use a Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a link created like this:

```
Html.ActionLink("Holdings", "Index", "Holdings", new { id = greenbaby }, null)
```

it renders a link:

```
http://blah/Holdings/Index/greenbaby
```

I need

```
http://blah/Holdings/Index/?id=greenbaby
```

or

```
http://blah/Holdings/?id=greenbaby
```

Is there a way to get the ActionLink to do that?

Comment: It should. Can you add your RouteCollection content?

Comment: My Route collection is the default one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add special route for it:

```
//*returns blah/Holdings/?id=greenbaby 
    routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "MyRoute",
                    url: "blah/{controller}/?id={id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Holdings", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );


//*returns blah/Holdings/Index/?id=greenbaby 
        routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "MyRoute",
                        url: "blah/{controller}/{action}/?id={id}",
                        defaults: new { controller = "Holdings", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                    );
```

Comment: be sure to add this before your Default Route, the order of declaring routes matters